# C# getting strings until a certain element

Tags: c#, string

I need help regarding string manipulation in C#. I have a string in the format [text1|text2|text3|...]. What I want is to extract each of the strings between the separators and possibly save them into a list or something similiar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
string[] result = inputString.Split(new Char[] {'|'});
```

Though

```
string[] result = inputString.Split('|');
```

Will work just as well as there's a single character overload not shown in the MSDN.

This will give you an array of strings "text1", "text2", "text3" etc.

If your string really is bookended by "[" and "]" and you will need remove these as well. If these characters don't appear anywhere else in your string you can do that in a single call:

```
string[] result = inputString.Split(new Char[] {'|', '[', ']'},
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx)

Otherwise you'll have to trim the text:

```
string[] result = inputString.Trim('[',']').Split('|');
```

Comment: `inputString.Split('|');` works. The signature is `Split(params Char[] separator)`. No need for a `new Char[]{}`.

Comment: But the text starts with `[` and ends with `]`

Comment: @Oded - I thought so, but when I double checked to make sure I'd got the profile right it gave that.

Comment: MSDN is a bit funny there - the `params` is only shown in the actual overload page, no the listing of overloads.

Comment: @ChrisF: I would prefer `inputString.Trim('[',']')`. The text itself could also contain `'[', ']'`. Then the split would be incorrect.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - that is true.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx)(to remove the `[` and `]`) and `string.Split` to create the array:

```
string[] result = text.Trim('[',']').Split('|');
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

```
string[] array = "[text1|text2|text3|...]".Split('|');
```

Comment: Don't forget about `[` and `]`

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `string.Split()`

```
string[] result = "[text1|text2|text3]".Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split('|');
```

Result is array with 3 strings:

> [0] = "text1", [1] = "text1", [2] = "text1"